# Append list in a loop

Tags: python, append

I am missing something regarding append() in a for loop.  I have two lists and I want to replace an item in list root = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] say the first item index 0.  The other list is replacements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

here's some code:

```
root = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
replacements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = root.index('A')
new_list = []
for j in replacements:
    root[y]=j
    print root
    new_list.append(root)
```

but the output is messing with me and Python docs doesn't help.  There must be something with my append function.  as you can see I print root and the desired result occurs but when I look at new_list it repeats the last list eight times;

```
[1, 'B', 'C', 'D']
[2, 'B', 'C', 'D']
[3, 'B', 'C', 'D']
[4, 'B', 'C', 'D']
[5, 'B', 'C', 'D']
[6, 'B', 'C', 'D']
[7, 'B', 'C', 'D']
[8, 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

and new_list:

```
[[8, 'B', 'C', 'D'], [8, 'B', 'C', 'D'], [8, 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
[8, 'B', 'C', 'D'], [8, 'B', 'C', 'D'], [8, 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
[8, 'B', 'C', 'D'], [8, 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
new_list.append(root)
```

With:

```
new_list.append(root[:])
```

The former appends to `new_list` *a pointer to `root`*.  Each pointer points to the same data.  Every time that `root` is updated, each element of `new_list` reflects that updated data.

The later appends to `new_list` *a pointer to a copy of `root`*.  Each copy is independent.  Changes to `root` do not affect copies of `root` that were made previously.

#### A simpler example

Compare this:

```
>>> root = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> b = root
>>> b[0] = 1
>>> root
[1, 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

With this:

```
>>> root = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> b = root[:]
>>> b[0] = 1
>>> root
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: so the [:] is really a slice of the entire root list - as you say a pointer to the copy of the entire list.  Any reason why it just pointed to the last iteration?  Thanks, it worked

Comment: @gatorNation (a) Yes, `[:]` makes a slice of the whole list and python interprets this to mean that it should make a copy  of the data.  (This is not obvious -- you just have to remember that this will require a copy to be made.)  (b) In the version without `[:]`, `root` is updated with every iteration.  Only the most current iteration is remembered.

Answer (score 0):

John1024 has a great solution, I just want to add one more solution here:

```
new_list = []
counter = 0
for j in replacements:
    root[y]=j
    new_list.append([])
    new_list[counter].extend(root)
    counter += 1
```

Hopefully this might be helpful for you